# React native app is taking time to load assets?

Tags: react-native

My react native android app is not loading some png files ,and taking time to load them ,sometime it loads sometime it wont,all the png are static files

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Answer (score 0):

Try using `react-native-cached-image` to cache the images.

`npm install react-native-cached-image --save`

Its been a ongoing bug in the react native community

Comment: Its only happening in android studio,and its about local images not remote ,files are png in format ,its making the app running slow and i can see my header is missing,some icons are missing ,when i go to other page and redirect again on that screen ,then i see header is there and other icons are missing

Answer (score -1):

The problem is resolved.Actually the pixels of images are very large like which make the app jerking. So its better to use the icon having proper resolution like 64X64 128X128.In my case the icons resolutions are 1400X1200 which doesn't load the image in android .